# Passing a struct array into a function and performing sizeof operation upon it

Tags: arrays, string, element, sizeof, struct

I suppose much like standard arrays (i.e integer arrays), when you pass an array of structs you must pass the size of the array with it. However what I do not yet understand is that when you take sizeof a structure first element you will get 4 (meaning 4 bytes in the first element?).

Now I pass a array of structs which contains only strings. I inspect the size of a single array element (remember it will be one struct) I get something like 28, but after I've passed it into a function (and yes by passed into the function I mean passed by value the address of the first element in my array), I only get 4.

Now I'm guessing the sizeof is getting the first element of my struct in the array. So I have my array myArray of type myStruct:

myStruct {
String name
String address
String postcode
}

I presume sizeof is looking at "name"? But I know for a fact that name isn't 4 bytes long - it's 10.

What exactly is the sizeof looking at? What does the memory structure look like of an array of structs?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: please indicate the language when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

The 4 will be the size of the pointer you have passed rather than the size of the struct to which it refers.

Comment: ahh (see my post). I tried dereferencing it and i get 32. Now why is that as the first element in my list is a type i've defined to be a string of 10 chars?

Comment: we can't answer that without your struct definition and knowledge of platform and compiler

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof()` works with types, not objects. `sizeof(some_object)` is implicitly taken as — using pseudo notation — "`sizeof(typeof(some_object))`".